# Send specific text in log to telegram api using curl

Tags: curl, telegram

I have a bash that send a message to telegram api using curl (one line code). Now, I want to send specific line (always line 7) or specific text from line "thistxtlog=message" in the log to telegram api using curl.

I have this

```
curl -X POST --silent --output /dev/null https://api.telegram.org/token/sendMessage -d chat_id=-id -d text=Hello+World
```

Now I want to replace the "text" in the curl to the text from log so that the message will be the text in the log and send it to telegram api.

I am new to linux and I don't know to use cat|grep|sed to embed in curl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply replace `Hello+world` with `$(cat log)` or `cat log`, `$()` and `` means that you put a shell command in there and it will return the result.

Where `log` is the filename of your log file.

Comment: Thank you! Now I know how to use that dollar sign because in my last command I thought I have to make a variable first. When I use the cat command, it only send the first line of the file after the space will be disregarded. However, I find a way and use grep instead to search and display/send the specific text I want using grep -inoE 'url(\W+\w+){0,6}' file.log